# redirect www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain2.com/try.html

Tags: nginx, rewrite

My nginx server has two server_name: mydomain.com and mydomain2.com

I'd like to redirect all requests from mydomain.com to mydomain2.com/try.html using a rewrite with the referer.

I am trying to do it with this rewrite:

```
               if ($http_referer ~* (www.mydomain.com) ) {
               rewrite http://mydomain2.com/try.html permanent;
       }
```

But it does not work.

Could someone help me...?

Regards and thanks.

Comment: You'll need to do better than "It does not work". What does that mean?

Comment: It does simply nothing :(.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect users coming TO a domain or coming FROM a domain? Does the redirect happen when you visit mydomain.com or mydomain2.com? I'm a bit confused because you mentioned both domains are on the same server.

Comment: I am trying to redirect users coming from domain.com to domain2.com/tryHtml

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [nginx wiki: Pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites)

Your rewrite rule isn't matching for beginning of the string. Use a ''^'' to do so.

> rewrite ^ http://mydomain2.com/try.html permanent;

Alternatively, you can use

> return 301 http://mydomain2.com/try.html;